# Java: JTable not showing icons properly

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtable

In my application, I need to display file system files in a JTable. When I click on the JTree node (which is any system folder), the contents of that folder are shown in the JTable.

In the first column of the JTable (where the name of the file or folder icon is shown), the icon is fetched from the system icon and is displayed.
Every thing is working fine. However, the problem is that when the renderer renders icon, the icon of the first file (first row of JTable) is repeated in all rows. I mean the icon does not change in the subsequent rows of the JTable. Here my code is in which a render gets icon and the model displays it in the JTable

```
class KeyIconCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public KeyIconCellRenderer(String ext) {
        File file = new File(ext);
        Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
        setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

and here is code where I am using render to display

```
private class Selection implements TreeSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        Object[] myData= new Object[6];
        TreePath path = e.getPath();
        FileUtil util= new FileUtil();
        FileMetaData metaData;

        Vector<FileMetaData> vList = new Vector<FileMetaData>();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)treeMainView.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

        FileInfo info =(FileInfo)node.getUserObject();
        File filePath= info.getFilepath();
        vList=util.getChildList(filePath);
        dtModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

        for(int i=0;i<vList.size(); i++){
            Vector v= new Vector();
            metaData=(FileMetaData)vList.get(i);
            v.add(metaData.getName());
            tblMainView.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new KeyIconCellRenderer(metaData.getClientpath()));
            v.add(metaData.getClientpath());
            if(metaData.isDirectory()){
                v.add("");
            }else
            {
                v.add((FileHelper.getSizeString(metaData.getSize())));
            }
            if(metaData.isDirectory()){
                v.add("");
            }else
            {
                v.add(new Date(metaData.getTime()));
            }
            if(metaData.isDirectory()){
                v.add("Folder");
            }else
            {
                v.add("File");
            }
            v.add("Pending Upload");

            dtModel.insertRow(0, v);
        }
        tblMainView.repaint();
    }
}
```

as in the attached image, only the icon of the fist file is repeated in all rows,

Please help, it will be a huge favor,
Thanks

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: FYI: When you cross-post questions across the Internet, remember to check the wording of your question to make sure it still makes sense. You make reference to an attached image (I don't see one). I presume you are referring to the image attached to your question over at Code Ranch (http://www.coderanch.com/t/532283/GUI/java/JTable-Cell-Rendere-Not-showing)?

Comment: I have attached the image you used at Code Ranch.

Comment: Can you post the full code for a simple, working example of this problem (so they we can try it out on our computers)? There appears to be code missing (for example, where does `dtModel` come from?).

Answer (score 2):

[Your surface mistake is to reset the table column's renderer in the loop, each time hard-coding the current icon in the the renderer's constructor. Consequently, the file-icon is used for all.

The basic problem is that you don't seem to fully understand the concept of a [renderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender): it's there to display the cell data as it is delivered as a parameter in its getXXCellRendererComponent. So that's the place to look-up the icon to use. The way to go is to store the File object in the table cell and query the appropriate icon every time the method is called.

Cheers
Jeanette